# Issues with derby Database using a GUI

Tags: user-interface, derby, jform

I am asking this question because I was unable to find a similar question. I recently completed this college project where I made a console application that connected to the database and everything seemed perfectly fine. The method I used to connect to the database is this:

```
  private static Connection getConnection()
   {
       Connection connection = null;

       try   
      {
          String dbDirectory = "c:/murach/java/db";
          System.setProperty("derby.system.home", dbDirectory);


        String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:MurachDB2";
        String username = "";
        String password = "";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, password);
        System.out.println("connect works");
        return connection;
      } //end try connection statement

      catch (SQLException e)
    {
        for (Throwable t : e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("something went wrong on connection method");
        } //end for loop for errors
    } // end catch statement for connection error


    return connection;
   }
```

As I said before I created the console application and everything seemed fine and I turned it in. However, I wanted to experiment with something, I wanted to make another version of this application but instead a GUI application using Jform. I used all of the same classes as before, except that instead of a main class, I used a jform. The method and class is exactly the same, because the database didn't change locations in my folder, however when I run it in the Jform application I get a runtime error.

What it was a null point error and I knew it had something to do with connecting to the database because I wrote a System.out.Println in the catch SQL Exception to notify that something went wrong with the method. The connect to the database is fine with the console application, but my question is if there is any further measures I need to take when it comes to working with a JFrame application. Is there anything I am missing or is there any extra step I need to do. For further measures I will display the whole class that works with the database, and I will also use the event handlers in the Jframe.

I want to make this clear in which that I am not required to do this. I am just playing around with Java, and I could easily leave this alone without consequences, but I feel I really want to learn this so this is why I am asking for help. Any kind of advice or if any of you can let you know what I am missing I would really appreciate it.

*Edit*

adding error information

```
    >java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:MurachDB2
something went wrong on connection method
java.lang.NullPointerException
something went from with dislay part
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at CustomerInvoiceDB.getConnection(CustomerInvoiceDB.java:38)
    at CustomerInvoiceDB.getCustomers(CustomerInvoiceDB.java:67)
    at CutomerInvoice.displayButtonActionPerformed(CutomerInvoice.java:111)
    at CutomerInvoice.access$000(CutomerInvoice.java:24)
    at CutomerInvoice$1.actionPerformed(CutomerInvoice.java:57)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Include the actual error information in your question (that is, the results of the `e.printStackTrace();` call). Use this technique to make sure you get it all: https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: Sorry about that, I was trying to include that but the website was giving me issues, but let me try again.

Comment: The message ` No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:MurachDB2` means that you don't have `derby.jar` in the `CLASSPATH` of your application.

Comment: That would make sense but the interesting part is that I do have derby.jar in that classpath, and this is why I am confused. The interesting part is I made another version of this application, that is not a GUI but a console application, and it works just fine and it connects to that database. Does making this application a GUI application make a difference or affect the outcome of connecting to the database?

Comment: Well I feel I have to correct myself, what I really meant was that in the folder db the derby.jar file is in that folder, that is what I really meant. The derbytools.jar file is also included in that same folder as well, is there any further step I should take?

Comment: Generally speaking, just putting a jar in an arbitrary directory doesn't automatically include it in a CLASSPATH, although there are certain situations which are exceptions to that. CLASSPATH is unfortunately a very complicated beast, with 20+ years of intricate, complex behaviors. With CLASSPATH, I find it's best to be very explicit, and not count on subtleties. Start here to learn more: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html